# best collection for removing element

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

In my program i have a collection of edges ,they have to be ordered by the weight.

Somewhere in the program i have to process the collection , and each time i have to remove the maximum of the collection.

I have already used an ArrayList but i'm looking for a better solution(time efficiency):

```
public class Edge implements Comparable<Edge> {
private int weight;
public void setWeight(int weight) {
    this.weight = weight;**
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Edge o) {
    return o.weight - this.weight;
}
```

}

what i did :

```
    private ArrayList<Edge> listOfEdges = new ArrayList<>();
    // i suppose here adding some edges in the list

    Collections.sort(listOfEdges);
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfEdges.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(listOfEdges.get(i).getWeight() + "   ");
    }
```

how can i get&remove the maximum of the list.
I have tested a treeSet but the edges can have the same weight, So what is the perfect Sorted Collection that accept a duplicate values.

Thank you

Comment: If it is sorted, then just remove the last item, or at least iterate from the end backwards

Comment: Maybe Priority queue or max heap? Can remove quickly and are sorted

Comment: thank you @cricket_007 , i will use a priorityQueue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my program i have a collection of edges ,they have to be ordered by the weight... I have already used an ArrayList but i'm looking for a better solution(time efficiency):

A binary tree like structure, such as a [heap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap) or priority queue, is what you are looking for. Once you have your object ordering (by the Comparable interface) specified, the maximum can be obtained in `O(1)` time, and removed in `O(log n)` time for `n` edges.

> how can i get&remove the maximum of the list.

peek and pop are the respective methods of a queue object implementation